# How to exit from npm publish if a file is missing?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-publish

I am running a `npm publish` which embeds a wasm binary file, and I want to check if the compiled file is not missing before actually publishing.

I guess I could use `prepublishOnly` with a custom shell command?
Is there any more specific rule to put into the *package.json* to do the job?

Comment: There's no other _"more specific rule to put into package.json"_ that I'm aware of. Use the `prepublishOnly` hook as you've suggested. For _*nix_ only, utilize a compound shell command to test if file exists, if it's missing then exit with a non-zero; E.g. `"prepublishOnly": "[ -f ./some/file.wasm ] || { echo \"Missing file.\" && exit 1; };"`. Or if cross-platform is a requirement then consider utilizing node.js in your npm-script instead. For instance: `"prepublishOnly": "node -e \"if (! require('fs').existsSync('./some/file.wasm')) { console.log('Missing file.'); process.exit(1) }\""`

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

`"prepublishOnly": "if [ -f wasm-file.js ]; then npm run any-custom-command-for-prepublish; else echo \"WASM files are missing.\"; exit 1; fi"`

Comment: I suggest checking your compound command using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) as this is not the logic you want. ShellCheck reports [this error](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015). Essentially your current logic is: if `[ -f wasm-file.js ]` is true but `npm run any-custom-command-for-prepublish` returns false, `{ echo \"WASM files are missing.\" && exit 1; }` will run.

Comment: The logic you want is: `"prepublishOnly": "if [ -f wasm-file.js ]; then npm run any-custom-command-for-prepublish; else { echo \"WASM files are missing.\" && exit 1; }; fi",`